# Servlets and .jsp pages (hosted within the same .jar as the embedder)

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I generate a jar file of an application containing an embedded **Jetty 8.1.8.v20121106** with a **jdk1.7.0_07** running on windows. However when I want to access the `index.jsp` I got the following error:`<br />HTTP ERROR 500`

Problem accessing /smpp/. Reason:

```
PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

Caused by:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:119)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:208)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:276)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:566)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

*** Jetty Startup***

```
D:\Applications\AppJars>java -jar unitysmpp.jar
2013-01-29/14:25:35.008 DEBUG: util.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.eclipse.jetty.util.log) via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2013-01-29/14:25:35.078 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - filterNameMap={}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.078 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - pathFilters=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.079 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletFilterMap=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.079 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletPathMap={/=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.079 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletNameMap={org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.105 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - filterNameMap={}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.105 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - pathFilters=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.105 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletFilterMap=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.106 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletPathMap={*.jsp=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, /=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-
1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.106 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletNameMap={org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1, or
g.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.137 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - filterNameMap={}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.138 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - pathFilters=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.138 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletFilterMap=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.138 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletPathMap={*.jsp=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, /HttpHandler=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.Reque
stHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1, /=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.139 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletNameMap={org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1, or
g.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.
Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.219 DEBUG: configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - FileName set to smpp-config.properties
2013-01-29/14:25:35.221 DEBUG: configuration.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is smpp-config.properties
2013-01-29/14:25:35.222 DEBUG: configuration.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file smpp-config.properties at null: no protocol: smpp-config.properties
2013-01-29/14:25:35.229 DEBUG: configuration.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the context classpath (smpp-config.properties)
2013-01-29/14:25:35.229 DEBUG: configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - Base path set to rsrc:smpp-config.properties
2013-01-29/14:25:35.299 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32 + SocketConnector@localhost:8080 as connector
2013-01-29/14:25:35.301 DEBUG: component.Container - Container o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} + org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPag
eErrorHandler@4436f0c9 as error
2013-01-29/14:25:35.302 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@72fa3f1b + o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,r
src:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} as handler
2013-01-29/14:25:35.302 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32 + org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollecti
on@72fa3f1b as handler
2013-01-29/14:25:35.302  INFO: Portal.WebStartup - Starting Jetty Web Container....
2013-01-29/14:25:35.303 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32
2013-01-29/14:25:35.305  INFO: server.Server - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2013-01-29/14:25:35.360 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32 + qtp890550801{8<=0<=0/254,-1} as threadpool
2013-01-29/14:25:35.360 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@72fa3f1b
2013-01-29/14:25:35.361 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.394 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - Thread Context classloader java.net.URLClassLoader@3238c403
2013-01-29/14:25:35.394 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.We
bInfConfiguration@240766c0
2013-01-29/14:25:35.401 DEBUG: webapp.WebInfConfiguration - Set temp dir C:\Users\superman\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-localhost-8080-Portal-_smpp-any-
2013-01-29/14:25:35.403 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.We
bXmlConfiguration@2d9c1743
2013-01-29/14:25:35.463 DEBUG: xml.XmlParser - parse: jar:rsrc:jetty-webapp-8.1.8.v20121106.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
2013-01-29/14:25:35.469 DEBUG: xml.XmlParser - parsing: sid=jar:rsrc:jetty-webapp-8.1.8.v20121106.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml,pid=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.504 DEBUG: webapp.WebDescriptor - jar:rsrc:jetty-webapp-8.1.8.v20121106.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml: Calculated metadatacomp
lete = True with version=2.5
2013-01-29/14:25:35.505 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Me
taInfConfiguration@8453227
2013-01-29/14:25:35.505 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Fr
agmentConfiguration@76dfa2ae
2013-01-29/14:25:35.505 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Je
ttyWebXmlConfiguration@54318a7a
2013-01-29/14:25:35.548 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - configure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebIn
fConfiguration@240766c0
2013-01-29/14:25:35.549 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - configure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXm
lConfiguration@2d9c1743
2013-01-29/14:25:35.561 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - configure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaI
nfConfiguration@8453227
2013-01-29/14:25:35.561 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - configure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Fragm
entConfiguration@76dfa2ae
2013-01-29/14:25:35.562 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - configure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Jetty
WebXmlConfiguration@54318a7a
2013-01-29/14:25:35.566 DEBUG: webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration - Configuring web-jetty.xml
2013-01-29/14:25:35.571 DEBUG: webapp.MetaData - metadata resolve o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.598 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - filterNameMap={}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.599 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - pathFilters=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.599 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletFilterMap=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.603 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletPathMap={*.jsp=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, /HttpHandler=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.Reque
stHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1, /=default}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.607 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletNameMap={default=default, org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1=org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Def
aultServlet-1, org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1=com
.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.612 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - filterNameMap={}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.615 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - pathFilters=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.620 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletFilterMap=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.624 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletPathMap={*.XSP=jsp, *.JSPX=jsp, *.jspf=jsp, *.jsp=jsp, /HttpHandler=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.Reque
stHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1, *.JSPF=jsp, *.jspx=jsp, *.xsp=jsp, /=default, *.JSP=jsp}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.628 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletNameMap={jsp=jsp, default=default, org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1=org.eclipse.jetty.se
rvlet.DefaultServlet-1, org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProces
sor-1=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.647 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1 as se
rvlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.648 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1 as servle
t
2013-01-29/14:25:35.648 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpReq
uestProcessor-1 as servlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.652 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + default as servlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.656 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + jsp as servlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.661 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + [/]=>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1
as servletMapping
2013-01-29/14:25:35.665 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + [*.jsp]=>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1
as servletMapping
2013-01-29/14:25:35.670 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + [/HttpHandler]=>com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.Request
Handlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1 as servletMapping
2013-01-29/14:25:35.674 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + [/]=>default as servletMapping
2013-01-29/14:25:35.678 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039 + [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.
JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp as servletMapping
2013-01-29/14:25:35.683 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@5843ae41 + org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletH
andler@247039 as handler
2013-01-29/14:25:35.687 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@43655aac + org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSe
curityHandler@5843ae41 as handler
2013-01-29/14:25:35.691 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@43655aac + org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSe
ssionManager@3323f4c5 as sessionManager
2013-01-29/14:25:35.695 DEBUG: component.Container - Container o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} + org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.S
essionHandler@43655aac as handler
2013-01-29/14:25:35.700 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@43655aac
2013-01-29/14:25:35.704 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@3323f4c5
2013-01-29/14:25:35.712 DEBUG: component.Container - Container org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32 + org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@5
2d8a522 as sessionIdManager
2013-01-29/14:25:35.713 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@52d8a522
2013-01-29/14:25:35.717 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager@52d8a522
2013-01-29/14:25:35.722 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@3323f4c5
2013-01-29/14:25:35.725 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@5843ae41
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.738 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039
2013-01-29/14:25:35.742 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - filterNameMap={}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.746 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - pathFilters=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.750 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletFilterMap=null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.754 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletPathMap={*.XSP=jsp, *.JSPX=jsp, *.jspf=jsp, *.jsp=jsp, /HttpHandler=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.Reque
stHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1, *.JSPF=jsp, *.jspx=jsp, *.xsp=jsp, /=default, *.JSP=jsp}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.759 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servletNameMap={jsp=jsp, default=default, org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1=org.eclipse.jetty.se
rvlet.DefaultServlet-1, org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1=org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1, com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProces
sor-1=com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.763 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039
2013-01-29/14:25:35.767 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@247039
2013-01-29/14:25:35.771 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@5843ae41
2013-01-29/14:25:35.775 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@5843ae41
2013-01-29/14:25:35.780 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@43655aac
2013-01-29/14:25:35.784 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler@43655aac
2013-01-29/14:25:35.788 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.792 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@4436f0c9
2013-01-29/14:25:35.796 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@4436f0c9
2013-01-29/14:25:35.800 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@4436f0c9
2013-01-29/14:25:35.806  INFO: handler.ContextHandler - started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.808  INFO: handler.ContextHandler - started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.813 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1
2013-01-29/14:25:35.816 DEBUG: servlet.Holder - Holding class com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor
2013-01-29/14:25:35.826 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED com.smsgh.unitysmpp.Http.RequestHandlers.HttpRequestProcessor-1
2013-01-29/14:25:35.827 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting jsp
2013-01-29/14:25:35.828 DEBUG: servlet.Holder - Holding class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.912 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED jsp
2013-01-29/14:25:35.912 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1
2013-01-29/14:25:35.913 DEBUG: servlet.Holder - Holding class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.917 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-1
2013-01-29/14:25:35.921 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting default
2013-01-29/14:25:35.924 DEBUG: servlet.Holder - Holding class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.939 DEBUG: servlet.DefaultServlet - resource base = null
2013-01-29/14:25:35.939 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED default
2013-01-29/14:25:35.940 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1
2013-01-29/14:25:35.944 DEBUG: servlet.Holder - Holding class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
2013-01-29/14:25:35.948 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1
2013-01-29/14:25:35.953 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - postConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.W
ebInfConfiguration@240766c0
2013-01-29/14:25:35.957 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - postConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.W
ebXmlConfiguration@2d9c1743
2013-01-29/14:25:35.960 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - postConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.M
etaInfConfiguration@8453227
2013-01-29/14:25:35.965 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - postConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.F
ragmentConfiguration@76dfa2ae
2013-01-29/14:25:35.970 DEBUG: webapp.WebAppContext - postConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.J
ettyWebXmlConfiguration@54318a7a
2013-01-29/14:25:35.974 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/smpp,rsrc:com/smsgh/unitysmpp/Portal/}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.978 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@72fa3f1b
2013-01-29/14:25:35.981 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@72fa3f1b
2013-01-29/14:25:35.986 DEBUG: handler.AbstractHandler - starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32
2013-01-29/14:25:35.990 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting qtp890550801{8<=0<=0/254,-1}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.997 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED qtp890550801{8<=0<=8/254,0}
2013-01-29/14:25:35.999 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting SocketConnector@localhost:8080
2013-01-29/14:25:36.008 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting null/null
2013-01-29/14:25:36.018 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@16384,0/1024@-]/PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@32768,0/
1024@-]
2013-01-29/14:25:36.029  INFO: server.AbstractConnector - Started SocketConnector@localhost:8080
2013-01-29/14:25:36.030 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED SocketConnector@localhost:8080
2013-01-29/14:25:36.031 DEBUG: component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6f8a8b32
2013-01-29/14:25:36.035  INFO: Portal.WebStartup - Jetty Web Container running....
```

Answer (score 0):

How are your java_home and path variables defined? Do they point to the jre or the jdk installation?

Could you post the start of your jetty startup log?

Comment: I have fixed it. First I download the ecj.jar and add to the classpath of the application and set the system property programmatically like this : System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "true"). Thanx for your help